# How can I make this Tkinter text widget read only?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self.lblLabel= Label(self.f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'), text="Read Only", bd=14, anchor='r')
self.lblLabel.grid(row=1,column=1)
self.txtLabel=Entry(self.f1,font=('arial',16,'bold'), textvariable=self.rander,
                    bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="red", justify = 'left')
self.txtLabel.grid(row=2,column=2)
```

I'm basically generating a random integer (`self.rander`) and displaying it in this text widget. How can I make it read only?

Comment: Use a Label rather than an Entry?

Comment: Or you can pass "state=DISABLED" when creating the Entry. See here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm